# $g'(x) = cg(x)$. Are there any other functions, aside from ${e^{cx}}$, that satisfy the condition?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Assume that $g:\mathbb R \longrightarrow  \mathbb R$ and $g'(x) = cg(x)$, where $c\in\mathbb R$ and $\forall\ x\in\mathbb R$.

Are there any other functions, aside from ${e^{cx}}$, that satisfy the condition?

P.S If there are not, how can it be proven?

Comment: Constant functions.

Comment: $Ae^{cx}$? :-) But no, aside from that there are no other solutions; this is a very standard _uniqueness theorem_ for the solution of this first-order differential equation.

Comment: just $k e^{cx},$ that's it

Answer (score 7):

Besides the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for differential equations, you can note that $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(e^{-cx} g(x)\right) = 0$$
so $e^{-cx} g(x)$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rigorous proof of this. Basically we are guaranteed one and only one linearly independent solution to this first order differential equation. In this case, $e^{cx}$.